# Determining whether a struct member has valid data before trying to free() it

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I am using the code below to free up `malloc`ed memory in the `meshes` struct, which contains `triangleArrays` and `faces`.

This crashes because not every position in the `struct` has data. What I want to do is only call `free` if the `struct` contains data at that member of the array. However using `if (self.meshes[meshIdx].triangleArrays[triangleArrayIdx].faces !=NULL)` does not seem to work.

```
for (int meshIdx = 0; meshIdx <=meshTriangleArrays; meshIdx ++) {
    for (int triangleArrayIdx = 0; triangleArrayIdx <=1; triangleArrayIdx ++) {
        if (self.meshes[meshIdx].triangleArrays[triangleArrayIdx].faces !=NULL) {
            free(self.meshes[meshIdx].triangleArrays[triangleArrayIdx].faces);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the ones without data are initialized to NULL when you create your meshes. Otherwise they will have a garbage value likely pointing to invalid memory.

Comment: Precisely in what way does it not seem to work?  And exactly how does the code which allocates the structures work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `free` on a null pointer is actually fine.

You haven't given enough code to fully diagnose this problem, but a few things to look at:

- You need to make sure that `self.meshes[...].triangleArrays[...].faces` is always initialized, either by a call to `malloc` (or whatnot), or by setting it to `NULL`. Otherwise it can (and likely will) be a random garbage pointer that you don't have permission to `free`.
- You need to make sure that all the different `self.meshes[...].triangleArrays[...].faces` pointers are *distinct* pointers. You are only allowed to call `free` exactly once on a `malloc`'d pointer. For example, something like this:

  ```
  int * p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  free(p);
  free(p); // undefined behavior
  ```

  can cause a crash.

Answer (score 1):

> The below code crashes because not every position in the struct has data.

No, it doesn't crash due to passing a NULL pointer to `free()`.  If you pass in a NULL pointer nothing happens, see [the documentation.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/free/)

What error is being thrown?  Show us your initialization code as well, i.e., how are you allocating `faces` and everything above it?  You are likely passing in some bad/uninitialized data to `free()`.

BTW, due to the way you have asked this question I am lead to believe that you think simply declaring an array will fill every element with `NULL`.  This is not the case, they may be filled with anything, and if you pass that to `free` you will crash (if you're lucky).

Comment: Right - that's what I was thinking - I am calling free on an array item which contains nothing - what I want to do is skip calling free on an array item that contains nothing. That's what I was (wrongly) trying to achieve by !=NULL

Answer (score 0):

How was the triangleArrays array created in the first place? Is it possible that the non-allocated members contain garbage instead of NULL?